# What are the approaches to private computations?

Tags: memory-hardware

I'm talking about the ability to safely run a virtual machine on a physical device that is not trusted. It is necessary that the owner can not access the data that the virtual machine operates on.
I am interested in what theoretical or practical implementations exist without special hardware.

I know about homomorphic computations (this in theory fully satisfies my question), but for now it's incredibly slow. It will take many years before the protocols of homomorphic calculations just approach application in practice.

I also read about Intel SGX, which implements enclaves. The RAM stores only encrypted data, which is decrypted at the input to the processor and is again encrypted at the output. The disadvantage of Intel SGX is that you need special hardware.
How could you do without a special hardware? How can we store a key for decrypting data from RAM so that the owner of this physical device can not recognize this key?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  When you ask "How could you do without", a word seems missing.  What is it you want to do?  It seems like you already understand the situation so I'm not sure what kind of answer you are expecting.